# PHP upload form won't upload more than 16 files

Tags: php, html, file-upload

The files are relatively small XMLs that are far below the max upload limit, and I've adjusted my max_file_upload value in php.ini to 30. All of the files can be uploaded in any combination up to 16 of them. What's more, the form will not actually "POST." It will action over to the next page, but I've put in some code to display text if the form has been submitted, which it won't if more than 16 files are selected. I'm at a loss for this one, not much help around the web either.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" action="?pa=uxf">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="fileField"><strong>Upload XML Files to Repository:</strong></label><br /><?php
            if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
                $fileCount = count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

                echo '<br /><br />File Count: '.$fileCount.'<br />';

                for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                    echo '<br />';
                    $target_dir = 'uploads/';
                    $target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i]);
                    $uploadOk = 1;
                    $fileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $check = filesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i]);
                    if($check !== false) {
                        echo '<span style="color: #00AA00">File is an xml.</span><br />'.$check['mime'];
                        $uploadOk = 1;
                    } else {
                        echo '<span style="color: #FF0000">File is not an xml.</span><br />';
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                        echo '<span style="color: #FF0000">Sorry, <strong>'.$target_file.'</strong> already exists.</span><br />';
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'][$i] > 50000000) {
                        echo '<span style="color: #FF0000">Sorry, your file is too large. Must be less than 50MG.</span><br />';
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if($fileType != 'xml') {
                        echo '<span style="color: #FF0000">Sorry, only XML files are allowed.</span><br />';
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                    }
                    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                    echo '<span style="color: #FF0000">Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</span><br />';
                    } else {
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_file)) {
                        echo '<span style="color: #00AA00">The file '.basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i]).' has been uploaded.</span><br />';
                        } else {
                        echo '<span style="color: #FF0000">Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</span><br />';
                        }
                    }
                }
            } ?>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td><input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload[]" multiple></td>
                                </tr>
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td><input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Upload XML"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table></td>
                <td valign="top"><strong>Uploaded Files List:</strong><br><?php
            $int = 1;
            foreach (new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $fileInfo) {
                if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
                $file =  $fileInfo->getFilename();
                echo $int.'. <a href="'.$directory.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><br />';
                $int++;
            } ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
```

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); can you add this two lines if you didn't already..Maybe there is an error about one of your controll arguments..

Comment: I added these two lines much higher up in my document, but I solved my issue already. But thank you very much for contributing to a solution, aaronxxx :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [max_file_upload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads), there are two other ini settings that concern file uploads that may be relevant.

[upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) (default 2 MB) limits the per-file upload size, and [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) (default 8 MB) limits the total size of POST content, including file uploads.

If you are running afoul of either limit, that can result in the behavior you are seeing.

As both of these are relevant before php code beings executing, you'll need to look at your `php.ini` (and/or `.htaccess` settings, as the case may be) and ensure that they are set to a level that will allow for all of your POST content to be accepted.

Comment: @cale_b Well, the community may downvote the answer, but it is an attempt to answer, so please don't flag such posts.

Comment: Perfect, this solved my problem :), I really should have read through php.ini further before bothering SO. Thank you very much for your answer jbafford.